# How do I add custom validators in JOI 17?

Tags: javascript, joi

I'm on JOI 14 and can't seem to find upgrade guides to move towards 17. I see people posting similar questions for JOI 16, but the last update was 3 months ago. It doesn't look like `type` was required back in 16 based on what I see in [How to add custom validator function in Joi?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58425499/how-to-add-custom-validator-function-in-joi).

I am looking at https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0#extensions and the description of `type` is `The type of schema. Can be a string, or a regular expression that matches multiple types.`.

I tried something like this:

```js
    const snakeAlpha = joi => {
      return {
        type: 'object',
        name: 'snakeAlpha',
        base: joi.string().regex(/^[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*$/)
      };
    };
    
    const customJoi = Joi.extend({
      type: 'object',
      rules: {
        snakeAlpha
      }
    });
```

It gives me this error:

```js
    ValidationError: {
      "type": "object",
      "rules": {
        "snakeAlpha" [1]: "[joi => {\n  return {\n    type: 'object',\n    name: 'snakeAlpha',\n    base: joi.string().regex(/^[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*$/)\n  };\n}]"
      }
    }
    
    [1] "rules.snakeAlpha" must be of type object
```

I am confused since  said `object`. I also tried `string` since that's what the base is, but it had same error message.

**Update**
I also realize the original example only covered one simple rule that isn't referencing joi (regex). I also have validators that reference other custom ones lke the below. Bonus points to solve this case too.

```js
const arrayKebabAlpha = joi => {
  return {
    type: 'string',
    name: 'arrayKebabAlpha',
    base: joi.array().items(joi.kebabAlpha())
  };
};
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation for Joi extensions is disappointingly lacklustre for such a useful feature. Fortunately a lot of Joi's core is written using extensions so a lot can be learned from looking at [the source](https://github.com/sideway/joi/blob/master/lib/types/string.js#L50).

If I were to write your rule as an extension it'd be like this:

```
const customJoi = Joi.extend(joi => ({
    type: 'string',
    base: joi.string(),
    messages: {
        'string.snakeAlpha': '{{#label}} must be snake case'
    },
    rules: {
        snakeAlpha: {
            validate(value, helpers)
            {
                if (!/^[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*$/.test(value))
                {
                    return helpers.error('string.snakeAlpha', { value });
                }

                return value;
            }
        }
    }
}));
```

Which can be used like:

```
customJoi.object().keys({
    foo: customJoi.string().snakeAlpha()
});
```

**UPDATE**

Whether this is the correct way of working with dependant extensions, I'm not sure, but this is how I typically handle them...

I first define my extensions in an array ensuring dependant extensions are defined first. Then I'll iterate through the array re-using the previous `customJoi` instance so the next extension includes those defined before it. A simple working example will probably explain better than I can put into words!

(I've also simplified the extensions to be more inline with how you're used to using them)

```
const Joi = require('joi');

let customJoi = Joi;

const extensions = [
    joi => ({
        type: 'snakeAlpha',
        base: joi.string().regex(/^[a-z]+(_[a-z]+)*$/)
    }),
    // this instance of 'joi' will include 'snakeAlpha'
    joi => ({
        type: 'kebabAlpha',
        base: joi.string().regex(/^[a-z]+(-[a-z]+)*$/)
    }),
    // this instance of 'joi' will include 'snakeAlpha' and 'kebabAlpha'
    joi => ({
        type: 'arrayKebabAlpha',
        base: joi.array().items(joi.kebabAlpha())
    })
];

extensions.forEach(extension =>
    customJoi = customJoi.extend(extension));

customJoi.assert([ 'hello-world' ], customJoi.arrayKebabAlpha());
```

Comment: Hoo boy I used to do `customJoi.snakeAlpha()` so lots of code changes in order to use this but I'll give a whirl :)

Comment: I am updating my question for a case I realize that wasn't covered for a an old base like `joi.array().items(joi.kebabAlpha())` - referencing self

Comment: Doing `type: /(string|array)/,` solves part of the way :) just can't figure out how to do `items(customJoi.string().kebabAlpha())` in that context yet

Comment: @DaveStein, please see my update. Hopefully I've understood your predicament correctly!

Comment: Cool nearly all my tests pass now.  I should be able to figure the last few stragglers from API differences. Thanks!

Comment: `type: 'string',` pretty sure that should be `type: 'snakeAlpha'`